# Android ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS permission uses

Tags: android, permissions

Android contains a permission called  'ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS'. Normal location commands would involve accessing coarse/fine location. Does anyone know what kind of extra commands this permission allows the app to access ?

Thanks.

Comment: you can find additional information about 3 commands at [google group discussions](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gpstest_android/uCq9ff9re7Q)
there were three command under discuss:
<code> locationManager.sendExtraCommand("gps", "delete_aiding_data", null); Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); locationManager.sendExtraCommand("gps", "force_xtra_injection", bundle); locationManager.sendExtraCommand("gps", "force_time_injection", bundle); </code>
it would be grate if anyone can say more about each extra

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to a rough search in Android source code, it indicate that `LocationManager.sendExtraCommand()` need this permission exactly.

Documentation:  [sendExtraCommand(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#sendExtraCommand%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29)

Answer (score 22):

I only know of 1 command which can be uses when you have a slow GPS fix:

```
((LocationManager)YourActivity.this.getSystemService("location")).sendExtraCommand("gps", "delete_aiding_data", null);
```

and in the Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/location/provider/AbstractLocationProvider.java;drc=master;bpv=1;bpt=1;l=353, click on `onExtraCommand` if you don't see the "References" panel at the bottom, scroll down to "Overriden By", and click on each implementation to see what commands it supports.

Here's a list of commands supported by [GnssLocationProvider](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/location/gnss/GnssLocationProvider.java) (since all of the other implementations seem to do nothing or delegate to another one):

- `delete_aiding_data`: calls `deleteAidingData`
- `force_time_injection`: calls `requestUtcTime`
- `force_psds_injection`: sends a `DOWNLOAD_PSDS_DATA` message if `mSupportsPsds` is true
- `request_power_stats`: calls `requestPowerStats`