# android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS permission uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917888/android-access-location-extra-commands-permission-uses)

I was wondering...

What is the following android permission:

```
android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS
```

what does it give me more than the other **location** permissions?
what are those "extra commands"?

Comment: Same question [here][1]. Hope that will help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917888/android-access-location-extra-commands-permission-uses